# Definition and example for a matrix representing a non linear transformation?

Tags: matrices, geometry, projective-geometry

I'm studying and trying to grasp the math behind some basic projective geometry, I'm having troubles when things starts to be non-linear .

Model space, world space and eye space are all the products of linear transformations as far as I can tell, I have little to no doubts in asserting that ; the problems start when considering the geometrical frustrum that is representing the perspective projection . Also as far as I can tell the clipping process in NDC coordinates is non linear too, but I have a couple of doubts about this one since I don't really grasp the previous step yet so I can easily be wrong about the frustrum "warping" into the NDC cube .

There is also this really bad habit of not naming things the right way in projective geometry; for example there is this $w$ term in almost all the $4x4$ projective matrices that is usually $=1$, and this term is never defined for what it is or even associated to a real nomenclature / name, I just know that I'm supposed to leave it to $1$ and even changing the term to arbitrary values doesn't really change anything in the final rendered result .

Do non linear transformations can be defined in terms of matrix that are presenting themself in an $X$ generic form ? I have noticed that, at least in the case of projective geometry, there are divisions involving some of the entries in the matrices, mainly the ones on the diagonal, maybe there is a generic form involving algebraic divisions for each term that can express all the non linear transformations ? How do I recognize a non linear transformation by just looking at the algebra / matrix of the problem ?

To simplify further, can you write an example of a matrix that is showing a non linear behaviour and depict the geometry associated with this matrix and how the matrix itself is influencing its shape ?

Comment: Actually, those first three transformations you named are not in general *linear* either, but *affine*, since they don’t leave the origin fixed—translations are not linear transformations. However, by moving to homogeneous coordinates (adding the “$w$ term”), all of these transformations, as well as perspective projection and others, can be represented as linear transformations of this higher-dimensional space. If you’d like to learn more about what’s going on there, look up projective geometry and homogeneous coordinates.

Comment: @amd look up where ? I would like an explanation that goes back and forth between the representation and the actual geometry ; I can only find math articles that just use homogeneous coordinates out of the blue and you just have to pretend to understand them, or there are this cryptic opengl tutorials on projective geometry where they write you some matrices that are "good enough" for "most cases" . I would like to understand it in such a way that I can write my own code and math .

Comment: See MvG’s answer for some starting points. Another brief, but good overview of homogeneous coordinates is http://deltaorange.com/2012/03/08/the-truth-behind-homogenous-coordinates/. The University of Toronto (CSC418 lecture notes)[https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~hertzman/418notes.pdf] provide a nice development of perspective transformation and the use of homogeneous coordinates to linearize it.

Answer (score 2):

If you think about points using their normal cartesian coordinates, then applying a projective transformation essentially means performing three steps.

1. You homogenize the point, by appending a fourth coordinate set to $1$. So $P_1=(x,y,z)$ becomes $P_2=(x,y,z,1)$.
2. Then you multiply with some $4\times 4$ matrix, e.g. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}&a_{24}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}&a_{34}\\a_{41}&a_{42}&a_{43}&a_{44}\end{pmatrix}\qquad P_3=A\cdot P_2=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z+a_{14}\\a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z+a_{24}\\a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z+a_{34}\\a_{41}x+a_{42}y+a_{43}z+a_{44}\end{pmatrix}$$
3. Then you dehomogenize: you divide the coordinate vector by its last (“$w$”) coordinate, and drop that coordinate. You end up with
   $$P_4=\frac1{a_{41}x+a_{42}y+a_{43}z+a_{44}}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z+a_{14}\\a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z+a_{24}\\a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z+a_{34}\end{pmatrix}$$

So although step 2. all by itself might be seen as a [linear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map) in a four-dimensional space, the fact that your vectors are actually interpreted as [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) means that it's essentially a probably non-linear [projective transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_transformation) in a 3-dimensional [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space).

It is affine exactly if $a_{41}=a_{42}=a_{43}=0$ and linear if $a_{41}=a_{42}=a_{43}=a_{14}=a_{24}=a_{34}=0$. Both of these only make sense if $a_{44}\neq0$, in which case you might scale the whole matrix by $1/a_{44}$ to obtain a simpler representation which preserves the $1$ in the last coordinate of each input vector and thus avoids the division in step 3.

Homogeneous coordinates are actually equivalence classes. Scalar multiples of a given vector represent the same point. So if you decide to set $w=2$ in the first step, instead of the conventional $w=1$, then your vector $(x,y,z,2)$ actually describes the same point as the vector $(x/2,y/2,z/2,1)$. So by setting $w$ to a value larger than $1$, you're shrinking you input by that factor $w$. A value smaller than $1$ expands. Points with $w=0$ are somewhat special. Dehomogenizing them would lead to a division by zero. These are [points at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity). They represent directions in space, e.g. they are the points where parallel lines meet.

When dealing with projective geometry, it's usually best to leave the dehomogenization step for the very end of all operations. So you'd take your input, homogenize it, and then perform all subsequent transformations on homogeneous coordinates before dehomogenizing the result at the very end. By avoiding dehomogenization after every step, a point at infinity in some step may still end up in a finite position in your final scene, usually as some point visible on the (2d image of the 3d) horizon, so there are benefits beyond improved performance. Parts of your question sound like you're about to learn OpenGL programming or something like that. If that's the case, keep in mind that many OpenGL operations will perform the dehomogenization step implicitely, so it's perfectly all right to use homogeneous coordinates for the vertices of some polygons, or the coordinates of some texture lookup, or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

What is *"linear"* in linear algebra is with respect to a vector field over the underlying (scalar) field of elements. Nothing else.

If you allow to blow up your vector space to become large enough you can accomplish just about any "non-linear" behaviour by still using linear algebra. Example is a step function warning for when to put on soft hat on your head when you go out. If you are ok with 1 degree celcius precision you could have a 100 degree thermometer (100 dimensional vector space), a vector of one 1 and rest zeros represent each temperature and the output could be a scalar product with ones for the positions where it is cold enough and zeros elsewhere. It would be a function which is a step function in terms of the scalar (highly non-linear, even discontinous). Counting up and down the thermometer would be implemented by permutation matrices which are linear operations in terms of the vector field. Although the function directly treating the scalar temperature value would be highly "non-linear".

If you want to see some really advanced non-linear things you can build with linear algebra you should check out the matrix representation theory of groups. An easy example are the complex numbers which can be written as $\left[\begin{array}{rr}a&b \\ -b&a\end{array}\right]$. Complex numbers are not particularly "linear" in terms of the underlying scalar field when you multiply them, right? For example you probably know that numbers on the complex unit circle "rotate" when multiplying each other.